# Validate type of regex-matched string type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I would like to check whether provided value match defined regex-match string type. Based on that I would return proper value. I need that to properly override my method.

EXAMPLE

```
type RegexType =`${string}/:${string}`

function myFunction(url: string): string;
function myFunction<P extends RegexType>(
  url: P,
): number;
function myFunction<P extends string>(value: P) {
  // value is typeof RegexType if yes then reutrn numberFunction otherwise stringFunction
}


const numberFunction = (): number => 1;
const stringFunction = (): string => '1';
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDmEAeAVc0C8ADAJAbwGdgAnASwDt4BfAegC58izKqsAoNgMwFdyBjYKQD25KAFsQAMV4Dh5ABTdiAGzpQmFeAEo1GygG4uMwSPFTjcgDwAFKMmARyAEwKwEyNJAB88tlChKqlDWADRsOlDk3GIARhDEhjz8JqIS0slWtvaOLuokmj4AbgCGytwQatZaUHh+UDQ0UCVl0KSuoJBCnG6IqOhQpN0gEO0AFo5QxBDcJKJRsfHpsqZCwOPEAO5t0HrwSylsVBxsfCJEkdFxxPtyUBhQ8hHzV3deUACMhqfk57s3pvdHrp8pRXlAAOTvcH6IA)

I know that I can use regex inside of the function, but then I meet another problem, that type is not properly interfered for template string

```
type RegexType =`${string}/:${string}`

function myFunction<P extends RegexType>(
  url: P,
): number;
function myFunction(url: string): string;
function myFunction<P extends string>(value: P) {
  // value is typeof RegexType if yes then reutrn numberFunction otherwise stringFunction
  return value.match('\/:') ? numberFunction() : stringFunction();
}


const numberFunction = (): number => 1;
const stringFunction = (): string => '1';
const testValue = '123/:123';

// ERROR
const valueNum: number = myFunction(`${testValue}`);
// VALID
const valueNum123: number = myFunction('123/:123');
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=52&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDmEAeAVc0C8ADAJAbwGdgAnASwDt4BfAegC58izKqsAoNgMwFdyBjYKQD25KAFsQAMV4Dh5ADwAFKMmARyAEwKwEyNJAB8ACjZQo3YgBs6URQBo2AShvluYgEYRiAbi4zBIuJS-nJGFtZQTBTwzpEk0b48-AGiEtLJckoqSGqa2lGUxgBuAIaW3BA2io5QeKZQNDRQpeXQpNqgkEKcOoio6FCkPSAQHQAW6lDEENwkoq4eXumygULAE8QA7u3QBfDLKfXTwBaiLRUAdGIlwHxjRgDkADr0DzUA-FALnsQHoTU2PZ-ERGRy%20KgcNh8EREL5uH7A0QYKCglzwrxQDAGKAARl80PIsKBIUCyNRcWY8Ex2IeOIe%20JhwCgaiIADUyhVMVBaQAmADM9Bx-PpHEaUAAojAYAB5GBQxnNDkQABybjRi2IXLSJPIRlweBZwHZrVYYLYYtZAEEADIASQAIvLCUzziq3EK%20eqflrghkQbyBXQPW9vEA)

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want. Unfortunately it requires an `any` in the return statement, but the return type of the function causes an error as you wanted:

```
type RegexType =`${string}/:${string}`

function myFunction<P extends string>(value: P): P extends RegexType ? number : string {
  return value.match('\/:') ? numberFunction() : stringFunction() as any;
}

const numberFunction = (): number => 1;
const stringFunction = (): string => '1';
const testValue = '123/:123';

// ERROR
const valueNum: number = myFunction(`${testValue}`);
// VALID
const valueNum123: number = myFunction('123/:123');
```

Unfortunately, doing this can easily make way for potential type errors by making incorrect assumptions when you're not able to determine the type of a string, for example the following is considered correct in typescript, but will result in the error "valueNum.substr is not a function":

```
const testValue = '123/:123';
const valueNum: string = myFunction(`${testValue}`);
valueNum.substr(1)
```